# Perl Function getpeername()

Tags: perl, function, sockets

I use `getpeername()` multiple times in my 'Client' file,but after few times it fails saying

```
"Bad arg length for Socket::unpack_sockaddr_in, length is 0,
 should be 16 at /usr/opt/perl5/lib/5.8.8/aix-thread-multi/Socket.pm line 370."
```

How should i avoid it, what are its possible causes?

Is there any other alternative for`getpeername()`.

Comment: This is probably because your socket is closed.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment above, it sounds like you're suffering that the socket is closed. The `peername` method itself just returns a raw packed socket address, so in your program you'd likely be wrapping it with a call to `unpack_sockaddr_in` or somesuch. Hard to say with much detail here because you didn't post your source code.